# Getting NSUnknownKeyException when running app under Instruments

Tags: cocoa-touch, debugging, exception, uikit

I'm trying to scan my application (window based with xib) for memory leaks, but when I'm running the app with Leaks tool, it crashes with exception

> ```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIWindow 0x4d20ec0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key rootViewController.'
> ```

It's strange, the app runs well in simulator and on device.

App delegate code:

```
#import "myAppDelegate.h"

@implementation myAppAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize myController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

    [window addSubview:myController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
=}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Even stranger: UIWindow does have a `rootViewController` property (since iOS 4.0). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController

Comment: So, how this information can be helpful to me? The UIWindow in my project has outlet to root controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs when there's a property in Interface Builder that is not set correctly, or does not exist anymore (look for warnings in Interface Builder).

As to why it's crashing only in Instruments may be because it defaults to run against your release build, and there may be some optimizations that are less forgiving for faulty configurations.

Comment: You're absolutely right. There were incorrect connections made in IB. I've discovered them when eliminating multiple build Warnings. Anyway you've deserved this bounty)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in the normal simulator, or on device without issues?

Otherwise did you implement a custom root view, ie using a different launch NIB?

it would be best if you upload your app delegate code

Comment: without which issues? it does not work if UIWindow is not connected with rootController. it launches and stays running, but nothing's displaying.

Comment: can you post your app delegate code! Also what is your build target version and what version of Xcode bundle are you using